# What is the arithmetic mean of all positive integers less than $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> What is the arithmetic mean of all positive integers less than $1$?

I have this question from one year but still i not got solution of this question so please ...

Comment: Please, list all positive integers less than 1.

Comment: The arithmetic mean of an empty set is undefined.

Comment: I guess there are a few authors who follow the French custom (as in Bourbaki) and regard 0 as being positive, in which case the answer would be 0.

Comment: @DerekHolt: do they have a shorter way to denote the positive, non-zero integers?

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a good reason to define a value for the arithmetic mean of the empty set?  For example, "the empty product" is nearly always or always taken to be $1$.

Comment: @robjohn: I guess that would be the non-negative integers, but it gets very confusing!

Comment: @DerekHolt, 0 is positive?!

Comment: @StefanSmith, the empty sum is defined to be zero, so you get $0/0$, still not defined. If such averages were (reasonably) common, and some definition that doesn't lead to all sorts of contradictions is possible, statisticians would have defined some value by now...

Comment: @vonbrand : good point.  The only reason can think of for wanting to do this is if one wanted to find the arithmetic mean of the union of two finite disjoint sets, given their means and the fact that exactly one of them is the empty set.  Computing the mean of their union in the usual way gives you the same result no matter how you define the mean of the empty set, so this does not help.

Answer (score 4):

The sum of all positive integers less than $1$ is $0$.

The number of all positive integers less than $1$ is $0$.

The mean value is not defined, the same as $\frac00$ is not defined.

Comment: thanks now i understand ..

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic mean of all positive integers below $n$ is $\frac n2$. Inserting 1 here we get the answer, $\frac12$.

Comment: This follows a pattern past its usefulness. You cannot take the arithmetic mean of an empty set of integers.

Comment: @robjohn what the question is what the answer. If the question has any meaning at all, the answer is 1/2.

Comment: As a [vacuous truth](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), what you say is true. However, by the same reasoning, it is also true that if the question has any meaning at all, the answer is 42.

Comment: @robjohn no. wrong.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: what is the arithmetic mean of the integers in the set $\{\}$? Just because $\frac33=1$ and $\frac22=1$ and $\frac11=1$, are you willing to say that $\frac00=1$? Just because things cancel, it looks as if the sequence is $\frac n2$, however, it is really $\frac{n(n-1)}{2(n-1)}$.